# background worker blocking main thread .net

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

We are using background workder thread (C#.net) for performing some tasks asynchronously in windows application (developed using .net 3.5) ....Registered the Do_Work event (invoked by windows timer by calling RunWorkerAsync) which makes a webservice call to fetch the data . With this we found that whenever Do_Work is firing for fetching the data , there is a delay in processsing of main thread . for e.g

Scenario 1 :
Main Thread open forms in 2-3 seconds when Do_Work event is not fired

Scenario 2 :
Main Thread open forms in 5-8 seconds when Do_Work event is fired

Note : 
1.Both main thread , background workder (Do_Work) calls webservice for fetching the data
2.Background worker task is totally independent of main thread task
3.We are using multi-core machine only....

Any help is appreciable , thanks

Comment: Post the code please.

Comment: you can try to spin off new threads after creating a new thread. It would be like this Main Thread > new Thread > collection of threads that does the background process. and do not call wait in the main thread to wait untill all threads are completed.

Comment: This will depend on the machine architecture. Is this a multi-core machine? Are you updating the UI from the background worker? If so, you are requesting that the UI thread perform operations - this can slow other operations (such as opening additional forms) that occur on the UI thread.

Comment: What does "invoked by windows timer by calling `RunWorkerAsync`" mean?

Comment: I saw this code on the MSDN:  `Do While BackgroundWorker1.isBusy()  Application.DoEvents  Loop` I know this is VB.NET code but I think it's pretty easy porting it to C#. Hope this helps... It's hard to tell the real problem without some code though...

Comment: "Note : 1.Both main thread , background workder (Do_Work) calls webservice for fetching the data "  Why are you using the main thread to call the webservice?  You shouldn't be doing that kind of work in the main UI thread...

Comment: //Sample Code : 
Main Thread
Open Form :
1.Make a webservice call to fetch the data
2.Instatiate the form and load the form with data retrieved as mentioned above....

Comment: BackgroundWorker workerThread;

private void ShowData()
 {   workerThread = new BackgroundWorker();
   workerThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
   workerThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(workerThread_DoWork);
   workerThread.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(workerThread_RunWorkerCompleted);
}
  
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!workerThread.IsBusy)
                {
                    workerThread.RunWorkerAsync();
                }         
        }

Comment: void workerThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (!(sender as BackgroundWorker).CancellationPending) 
            {
                //SessionManager has SessionData as static variable
                if (SessionManager.SessionData != null)
                {
                
                   e.Result = data //data will be fetched by making a webservice call...SessionData is being passed to the webservice
                }
               
            }
        }

Comment: void workerThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{  
    Data = e.Result

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we are able to resolve the issue by applying below setting in the client configuration file ..

refer ....
blogs.msdn.com/b/darrenj/archive/2005/03/07/386655.aspx